# How to join between table DurationDetails and Table cost per program

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, erd

**How to design database for tourism company to calculate cost of flight and hotel per every program tour based on date ?**

what i do is

Table - **program**

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProgramID | ProgramName |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | Alexia      |
|         2 | Amon        |
|         3 | Sfinx       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

every program have more duration may be 8 days or 15 days only

it have two periods only 8 days or 15 days .

so that i do duration program table have one to many with program .

Table - **ProgramDuration**

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| DurationNo | programID |   Duration    |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|          1 |         1 | 8 for Alexia  |
|          2 |         1 | 15 for Alexia  |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

And same thing to program amon program and sfinx program 8 and 15 .

every program 8 or 15 have fixed details for every day as following :

**Table Duration Details**

```
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Days | Hotel  |       Flight       |    transfers      |
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Day1 | Hilton | amsterdam to luxor | airport to hotel  |
| Day2 | Hilton |                    | AbuSimple musuem  |
| Day3 | Hilton |                    |                   |
| Day4 | Hilton |                    |                   |
| Day5 | Hilton | Luxor to amsterdam |                   |
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

every program determine starting by flight date so that

if flight date is 25/06/2017 for program alexia 8 days it will be as following

```
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
|    Date    | Hotel | Flight | Transfer |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| 25/06/2017 |    25 |    500 |       20 |
| 26/06/2017 |    25 |        |       55 |
| 27/06/2017 |    25 |        |          |
| 28/06/2017 |    25 |        |          |
| 29/06/2017 |    25 |    500 |          |
+------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

And this is actually what i need how to make relations ship to join costs with program .

for flight and hotel costs as above ?

for 5 days cost will be 1200

25 is cost per day for hotel Hilton

500 is cost for flight

20 and 55 is cost per transfers

image display what i need

[relation between duration and cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WXf6.jpg)

Comment: If the details are fixed, wouldn't the total cost just be flights + transfers + ( hotel * 3 or 5)? Are the hotel costs the only thing that will change between 3 and 5 day itineraries? Although you're showing a 5-day itinerary but you said there will only be 8 and 15. I think I misunderstood something.

Comment: Im sorry for wrong it is is 8 or 15 for every program this is correct but i write until 5 days to brief writing and not writing more

Comment: every program have 8days or 15 days and based on details for every days i calculate cost as above

Comment: can any one help me please

Comment: if any thing not clear i can write

Comment: Here is how to explain a table: Use a sentence template (*predicate*); the columns are parameters. Eg for your final table: "on day *Date* program Alexia costs $ *Flight* for its flight from Amsterdam to Luxor and $ *Hotel* for a room at the Hilton hotel and costs $ *transers* for transfer 'airport to hotel'" Every table (base and query result) has a predicate. Rows that make a true statement go into the table.

Comment: Go to [sqlfiddle.com]. Write a comment that is a base table predicate. Define the base table (name, columns, types, PKs, FKs, other constraints). UPDATE the table to example data. Write a comment that is a query result predicate. Give its query. Run the query. Repeat all. When you are stuck ask a question. (Probably when you can't write a query.) Cut and paste its link, its code and its output into a question. Do not use images. The only (non-predicate) language needed is probably "What is a query for this predicate:". (*Maybe* some description of the business is helpful.) (But not much here.)

Comment: PS Your presentation is confusing when your descriptions of tables look like tables. Your presentation is confusing when you describe business situations but your example data doesn't agree with the situations. Your sentences like "x is y" are clear; your other sentences are not clear. Use smaller sentences. Use clear phrases to refer to things and their parts.

Comment: PPS The predicate I gave earlier was not for your final query result. It was for a table like your final table but without blanks. Also, a query statement result is not a table; it is like a table but its rows are ordered. It is called a result set. So if you care about order then you should describe it after a result set predicate. Learn to use tables (base and query results) with no NULLs or blanks. Then learn to use base tables with NULL. Then queries that input NULL. Then queries that add NULL. (OUTER JOINs do that.) Then queries that blank out values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truthfully, I don't fully understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Your description is not clear, your tables seem to be missing information / contain information that should not be in your tables, and the way that I'm understanding your description doesn't really make sense based on the UI screenshot that you shared.

It looks like you're working on an application for a travel agency which will allow agents to create an itinerary for a trip. They can give this trip a name (so if a particular package is a hit with customers, they can just offer the "Alexa" package), and the utility will calculate the total estimated cost of the trip. If I understand correctly, the trips will be either 8, or 15 days long.

Personally, I would delete the "ProgramDuration" table altogether. If there are two versions of the Alexa trip at index 1, then you're going to run into all manners of issues. I can get into the details of why this is a bad idea, but unless you're really hung up on having this ProgramDuration table, it's not worth the time. You should add a "duration" field to your "program" table, and assign a new ProgramID for each different duration version of the "Alexa" program.

Your table "Duration details" also misses the mark. Your fields in this table will make it harder to add new features to your application down the line. You should have a field "ProgramID," which we will use to join this table against the program table later. You should have a field "Day" which obviously indicates the day in the itinerary. You should have only one more field "ItemID." We're going to use the "ItemID" field to join your itinerary against a new items table we're going to create.

Your items table is where you define all of the items that can possibly appear in an itinerary. Your current itinerary table has three possible "types" of expenses, flights, hotels, and transfers. What if your travel agents want to start adding meal expenditures into their itineraries / budgets? What about activities that cost money? What about currency exchange fees? What about items that your clientele will need before their trip (wall adapters, luggage, etc.)? In your items table, you will have fields for an ItemID, ItemName, ItemUnitPrice, and ItemType. A possible item is as follows:

ItemID: 1, ItemName: Night At The Hilton, ItemUnitPrice: 300, ItemType: Lodging

Using the "SELECT [Column] AS [Alias]" syntax with some CTEs or subqueries and the JOIN operator, we can easily reconstitute a table that looks like your "Program Duration Details" table, but we will be afforded considerably more flexibility to add or remove things later down the line.

In the interests of security and programmability, I would also add a table called "ItemTypeTable" with a single field "TypeName." You can use this table to prevent unauthorized users from defining new item types, and you can use this table to create drop down menus, navigation, and all manners of other useful features. There might be cleaner implementations, but this shouldn't represent a serious performance or size hit.

All in all, at the risk of being somewhat rude, it seems like you're trying to take on a rather large, sophisticated task with a very rudimentary understanding of basic relational database design and implementation. If you are doing this in a professional context, I would strongly encourage you to consider consulting with another professional that may be more experienced in this area.

Comment: why delete programduration table i only create trip one time and every

Comment: time i calculate to fixed based program meaning program tour that company do know the way previously and not changed

Comment: YES YES It looks like you're working on an application for a travel agency which will allow agents to create an itinerary for a trip. They can give this trip a name (so if a particular package is a hit with customers, they can just offer the "Alexa" package), and the utility will calculate the total estimated cost of the trip. If I understand correctly, the trips will be either 8, or 15 days long.

Comment: The program duration table basically maps two different programs to one program id. The 8 day alexa program is fundamentally a different program than the 15 day alexa program. Even if the first 6 or 7 days are the same, there will be a flight home on the 7th or 8th day of the 8 day program that shouldn't appear in the 15 day itinerary. Consequently, we can't assign all of the itinerary items to one program id, and then only select those items where day <= 8 to get the 8 day itinerary. Once we start using the duration number to attach itinerary items, my solution uses fewer joins and tables.

Comment: I would suggest that you look into taking some courses / doing some tutorials, if you can spare the time. Otherwise, I might suggest that you look into finding a tutor / expert to spend some time to go over this project in greater detail with you. The complexity and open ended nature of your question / request makes it such that it would likely be faster for stack overflow contributors to set the DB up themselves and write your SQL for you, than it would be to type up a full how-to and explanation for your specific application.

Comment: This question merits comments, downvotes & closing (blocking answers until sufficiently improved) but not answers.